# Finding count of particular items from a list

Tags: c#

I have a `List<String>` with 1000 names. I want to find out the count of names which is starting with letter "S".

What will be the best option to do it?

Comment: Use LINQ, its not available in Framework 2.0

int count = myList.Count(name => name.StartsWith("S"));

Comment: Could you not have written code to simply iterate the list, test and keep a count in the time it took to write this question?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If Linq is available

```
using System.Linq;
list.Where(s=>s!=null && s.StartsWith("S")).Count();
```

if Linq is not available.

```
int count=0;
foreach (string s in list) {
  if (s!=null && s.StartsWith("S")) count++;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using linq makes this simple

```
var count = list.Where(x => x != null && x.StartsWith("S")).Count();
```

Comment: @Rawling, no, there may also be a method but i choose to use the property.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: No, `List<T>` has this property but not `IEnumerable<T>` which is returned by `list.Where`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to LINQ, something like

```
int count = myList.Count(name => name.StartsWith("S"));
```

Otherwise, something like

```
int count = myList.FindAll(name => name.StartsWith("S")).Count;
```

(Edit: as Bob Vale points out in his answer, if any of your list entries could be null, you need to add a null check e.g. `name => name != null && name.StartsWith("S")`.)

Comment: `c` isn't even defined :p Yeah I noticed that from your answer but thought I'd credit you with it in a parenthetical edit rather than just steal it.

Answer (score 1):

```
int k = 0;
foreach (string aName in yourStringList)
{
  if (aName.StartsWith("S"))
    {
    k++
    }
}
```

and `k` will have the number of names which starts with "S"

Comment: Although one can use Linq, +1

Comment: @BobVale: You're missing a `comment-to-all` button, aren't you? ;-)

Comment: I consider 'I have a List<String> with 1000 names' means that items have values - and gived the simpilest solution for Vishnu to get the point. If aName is null application should throw the exception. If that is unwanted behaivour, if sentence should be (aName != null && aName.StartsWith("S"))

Comment: _"`List<String>` with 1000 names'"_ does not mean that all items must have a value. Only OP could tell us.

Comment: You are right, so, if Vishnu wants that application would not throw an exception if there are items with null value, should add aName != null.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
...
int count = list.Count(c =>  c!= null && c.StartsWith("S"));
```

Comment: @BobVale How can c be null, it is a element of a generic list of strings

Comment: @BobVale I've tested it, good point, didn't know it is possible I'll edit the answer, thank you.